# Icon Requests -> migrate to Graphic Design?

Tags: discussion

We'd obviously want to vet this with the GD admins, but I was wondering if it made sense to migrate 'what icon should I use for...' questions over to Graphic Design?

We seem to get a lot of them as of late here on UX, but as it's off topic here, we close them.

However, I noticed that we do seem to allow questions like that over on Graphic Design. Perhaps we should be migrating instead?

Comment: As I said on the chat; "Strange there isn't a community anywhere, as far as I know, for discussing icons instead of just showing off their own or create a searchable database like dribbble/behance/iondeposit etc." - So why not create a new SE for icons?

Answer (score 5):

I recently popped into the Graphic Design chatroom to discuss how they'd feel about this idea. They were *mostly* ok with it, although have some reservations (too subjective, not really helpful to anyone other than the question asker...). However we're going to give it a go and start migrating these questions when they come up (providing they're reasonably good questions and not 'what logo should I have for my website' sort of things.

I posted on their meta site about it, so they may have more comments in future, so pop over there and see what you think.

https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/759/whats-a-good-icon-for-x

Comment: +1 that looks exactly what I tried to implement here. If this suggestion is accepted, there's no need for an Icons.SE. I'll follow the development on this suggestion. You are a clever!

Comment: Remember that the no. 1 rule to open the migration paths is **Do not migrate crap** (crap could mean any: subjective, unclear, too broad, off-topic in the target site, or duplicated)

Answer (score 2):

Icons have been discussed on UX since it's birth, and many have fought for bringing them down. My personal notes, previous questions and suggestions have been "put at rest". I know from education that visual representation is an aspect of User Experience. But I've also learned that icon request is not a part of UX.SE. Probably because UX.SE would be flooded with icon requests. Tonight we got three questions on the topic, at a site which averages on 12 new questions per 24 hours.

It's clear that this aspect of User Experience need a place to live, and I don't think that it's at Graphic Design. I think icons are a site if it's own, which I would commit to if it would be listed at Area 51. Who'll start the request for the Stack Exchange site Icons at Area 51?

Comment: Its live :) http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63677/icons

Comment: @Bluewater Listed!

Comment: @Bluewater: That proposal has been deleted.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, proposals are deleted if they do not receive any activity for a month :/